# How to execute a command after exception

Tags: java

I have a 2d array `someArray` with some system commands. Let's say I have these commands -

- `ls`
- `lol` (invalid command)
- `pwd`

the second command will trigger an `IOException` and the third command does not get executed. How do I make sure that the last command will get executed regardless of any exception? Any advice?

```
              for ( int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++ ) {
                 try{
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(someArray[index]);
                    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                    Process process = pb.start();

                    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String line;
                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    br.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.err.println( "Command not found" );
                }
             }
```

Comment: Use a `finally` after the catch block.

Comment: please show the complete code including your loop though the commands

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider how do I start from the next index?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using IOException in the catch use the general class Exception which will catch any kind of Exception thrown

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++ ) {
        try{
           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(someArray[i]);
           pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
           Process process = pb.start();

           InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

           String line;
           while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
           br.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println( "Command not found" );
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Unexpected Exception caught to continue other commands");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

edit: fixed to report the unexpected error

Comment: Catching `Exception` is bad practice. Especially when you’re not making sure you report all the exception details. There’s a great risk that some unknown exception that shouldn’t be caught here, gets caught and disguised so you won’t find out what went wrong.

Comment: I agree, but the question was explicit saying: "How do I make sure that the last command will get executed regardless of any exception".
For me it was enough catching IOException, as it would be the only known exception thrown when the command was erroneous

Comment: Respecting the bad practice comment..If the user can pass in anything, is it guaranteed that `Process` will/can always throw `IOException` ? What if it it has a different exception blocking it from continuing ? Just clearing out..

Comment: If `IOException` is the only checked exception you can have, you can always risk an unchecked exception. Such can be caught with `RuntimeException` if desired (so you still do not need `catch (Exception e)`).